# Nginx block access to url

Tags: nginx

I am using concrete5 and I need to disable /login url on my website. 
**Nginx** is my server.

I tried so far to allow access only to specified ips:

```
       location /login {
           allow 5.69.34.213;
           allow 5.80.29.130;
           deny all;
   }
```

But it did not work. It blocks **all** ips and the specified too. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
My conf file is:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_website.com;
    return 301 https://my_website.com$request_uri;
}

#HTTPS server

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my_website.com;

    root /var/www-staging/my_website/public_html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
    # openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

        location /templates {
                alias /var/www-staging/my_website/templates/dist;
        }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /login {
        allow 5.80.29.130;
        deny all;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/my_website_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_website_access.log;
}
```

Comment: Please show your complete nginx configuration.

Comment: This is the correct syntax, as documented here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html Please share your full configuration and also show us the access log to determine the client IP making the requests.

Comment: Just updated! Please help...

Answer (score 10):

nginx documentation explains your case: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration

> nginx first searches for the most specific prefix location given by
>   literal strings regardless of the listed order. In the configuration
>   above the only prefix location is “/” and since it matches any request
>   it will be used as a last resort. Then nginx checks locations given by
>   regular expression in the order listed in the configuration file. The
>   first matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this
>   location. If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses
>   the most specific prefix location found earlier.

so following this statement `/login` only matches if there is no regex that matches. If you access `/login/login.php` for example, your `location ~ \.php($|/)` wins the election on who gets to handle this request.

**SOLUTION 1**

To fix your problem set this location ABOVE the `php location`

```
location ~* /login {
    allow 5.80.29.130;
    deny all;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

use

```
location ^~ /login {
    allow 5.80.29.130;
    deny all;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location explains that `^~` disables regex matching if this prefix string location matches.

Comment: I did try both examples. Does not work. Adding my IP Nginx returns 404 Not Found.

Comment: Sounds like another thing is broken. Have a look at the access and error log to see of your request got handled by this vhost.

Comment: "**Nginx returns 404 Not Found.**" - this can be caused when working with CMS or framework, where routes are dynamically generated, for e.g. if we consider Drupal CMS, it servers all pages through index.php. So to get this working with Drupal, we've to add one more line to above 'location' block as `try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;`. This will re-write new url so it can be served with index.php. I've tried this solution with **Solution 1**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. I have a vagrant machine for that project where I could debug it step by step. PHP was making a **curl request** to an API which would take **forever**. I had to set a timeout to handle such a behaviour:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

and now check if **$response** if **false** ( no result )

```
if (!$response) {
        $this->writeFile('FALSE ' . $ip . ' ' . $session);
    } else {
        $this->writeFile('SUCCESS ' . $ip . ' ' . $session);
    }
```

That solved the problem. fpm socket was a misleading error. Rookie mistake...

I must find out how to talk to that API, apparently developers changed something last night and probably introduced a bug. It was working all this time.

Answer (score 0):

[Yogesh](https://serverfault.com/users/172416/yogesh) [suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/832975/nginx-block-access-to-url#comment1203898_833212) works for frameworks serving pages by index.php through internal router, e.g.: Symfony or Drupal. In this case the config should look as follows

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my_website.com;

    root /var/www-staging/my_website/public_html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
    # openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    location ~* /login {
        allow 5.80.29.130;
        deny all;

        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location /templates {
        alias /var/www-staging/my_website/templates/dist;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/my_website_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_website_access.log;
}
```